# Как настроить nexus для загрузки артефактов через прокси-сервер?

Tags: maven, nexus

Ситуация следующая. Поставил на виндовй сервер последнюю версию нексуса, запустил его кк сервис - тут все работает. Но вот выложить артефакт не получается.

Проблема еще и в том что в конторее имеется прокси-сервер. Его в settings.xml добавил. До того как добавил прокси была ошибка 405, теперь ошибка 401 - работаю под админом нексуса.

Вот сами настройки

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/settings/1.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd"> 
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <id>optional</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol> 
            <host>alva-cws02.alv.autoliv.int</host>
            <port>80</port> 
            <nonProxyHosts>http://myip:8081/repository</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy> 
    </proxies>

    <servers> 
    <server>
        <id>nexus</id>  
        <username>admin</username>  
        <password>admin123</password>   
    </server> 
    </servers>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nexusRepo</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories> 
                <repository>
                    <id>valRepo</id> 
                    <name>Valpro</name>
                    <url>http://myip/repository/val_repo_hosted</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>nexusRepo</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles></settings>
```

Вот файл пом

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://10.49.20.5:8081/maven-public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://10.49.20.5:8081/maven-public</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>maxifier</id>
            <url>http://10.49.20.5:8081/repository/val_repo_hosted</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>maxifier</id>
            <url>http://10.49.20.5:8081/repository/val_repo_snap</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
  <name>pluginTemplateApi</name>        
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <groupId>val_repo.pluginTemplateApi</groupId>
    <artifactId>CollectorPluginTemplateApi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>              
</project>
```

Прочитал что можно как то через зеркало сделать - но не получается на зеркало сплевывается ошибка 405.

Как правильно настроить нексус?

Comment: Прокси-сервер требует авторизацию? Пробовали добавлять `username` и `password` в настройки прокси? Например, как в примере: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: Нет данный прокси не требует учетных данных. Для других приложений как то обновление нет бинс работает прекрасно. Да и в данном случае видно что проблем с прокси нет - ошибка то меняется на 405